# Changing width of a div depending on presence or absence of other elements

Tags: html, css, width

I have two floated divs side by side. My left div takes up 30% of the allocated space and my right div takes up 65%. However my site is powered by a CMS and when there is no content in the left div, it is simply not displayed in the browser. This leaves me with just a 65% div and some empty space next to it which looks a little less than pretty. Is there a straight up HTML/CSS2 way to instruct my 65% div to take up the full amount of space allocated if the 30% div isn't displayed or does this necessarily involve jQuery and other such solutions?

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/futkt485/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Content on the left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Content on the right</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        <p>When there is only content in the right div, it needs to have a width value of 100%.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Content on the left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Content on the right</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p
    {
        padding: 10px;
    }

.container
    {
        overflow: auto;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
        color: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

.container .left
    {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        background: #555;
    }

.container .right
    {
        float: left;
        width: 65%;
        background: #c00;
    }
```

Comment: The answer is that CSS cannot decide that and you need to apply classes either using server side language or using js

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like :

```
.container .right
{
    float: left;
    min-width: 65%;
    width: auto;
    background: #c00;
}
```

(Not tested)

Answer (score 0):

A solution could use JavaScript instead for that, as you wont be able to decide where applying your style only by using CSS.

Here a quick example: http://jsbin.com/nijitemeqe/1/

The code check the present of `div` element with class `left`, if not present add a class `special` with css `width:100%` to your `right` elements.

In this example I have commented out divs with `left` class, probably your CMS want add in your final HTML.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    <style>
    p
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }

    .container
        {
            overflow: auto;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
            color: #fff;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

    .container .left
        {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            margin-right: 5%;
            background: #555;
        }

    .container .right
        {
            float: left;
            width: 65%;
            background: #c00;
        }
    .special {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    window.app = {
        start: function(){
        var left = document.querySelectorAll('.left');
            if(left.length === 0) {
                var right = document.querySelectorAll('.right');
                for(var i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
                    elm = right[i].classList.add('special');
                }
            }
        }
    };
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="app.start();">

    <div class="container">
        <!--div class="left">
            <p>Content on the left</p>
        </div>-->
        <div class="right">
            <p>Content on the right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="right">
            <p>When there is only content in the right div, it needs to have a width value of 100%.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!--<div class="left">
            <p>Content on the left</p>
        </div>-->
        <div class="right">
            <p>Content on the right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is the easyest way, for example:

```
<script>
if(document.getElementById('YOURID').style.BackgroundColor=='red'){
document.getElementById('IDOFTHEDIVTOCHANGE').style.width='300px';
}
</script>
```